# Change time format from 1/1/1900 10:00:00 PM to 10:00 PM

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I'm currently building a program to track the Login in / out, the data is exported as a string like this "5:00AM", I use the following code to convert the data from string to datetime64[ns]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'LoginTime' : ["10:00PM", "5:00AM", "11:00PM","7:00AM"],
                  'Logout Time' : ["6:00AM","2:00PM", "5:00AM", "5:00PM"]})

for c in df.columns:
      if c == 'LoginTime':
          df['LoginTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LoginTime'], format='%I:%M%p')
      elif c == 'Logout Time':
          df['Logout Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Logout Time'], format='%I:%M%p')
```

The output result is the following:

```
        LoginTime         Logout Time
      0 1900-01-01 22:00:00 1900-01-01 06:00:00
      1 1900-01-01 05:00:00 1900-01-01 14:00:00
      2 1900-01-01 23:00:00 1900-01-01 05:00:00
      3 1900-01-01 07:00:00 1900-01-01 17:00:00
      LoginTime      datetime64[ns]
      Logout Time    datetime64[ns]
```

The code works as expected and changed the string to time format, however, I noticed the format is 1/1/1900 10:00:00 PM, I would like to know if there's a way to get only the time like this 10:00:00 PM without affecte the data type as datetime64[ns] since I have to create validation for the Login in / out

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to display in one format but store it as another?

Comment: Add some example data so we can reproduce an answer for you. Example data can be as little as 5 rows.

Comment: @Erfan I just added the sample data, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dt.strftime` after converting it to `datetime` format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LoginTime':['1/1/1900 10:00:00 PM', '1/2/2018 05:00:00 AM']})

              LoginTime
0  1/1/1900 10:00:00 PM
1  1/2/2018 05:00:00 AM
```

---

```
df['LoginTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LoginTime']).dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')

  LoginTime
0  10:00 PM
1  05:00 AM
```

Comment: @Erfran thanks for your response, is there any way to get the same result without changing the data type datetime64[ns]